# ADO.NET Framework change tracking

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, change-tracking

i just wanted to ask if there is a way the reject all changes made to a ADO.NET Framework model with its relations?
[Auditing in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374889/auditing-in-entity-framework) describes a way the restore the original value of a single entity. But is this possible for all unsaved changes in the whole database?

Comment: Non of the methods below worked for me. Solution was to write a function which refreshed the whole entity set.

Comment: Great, you can reply on your own question and mark as correct, so anyone else with the similar problem can have more detailed view on the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non of the methods below worked for me. Solution was to write a function which refreshed the whole entity.

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.0 there is no automatic way to do it.
Look here how it can be done [Julie Lerman Programming Entity Framework](http://books.google.com/books?id=wp8V0vBebnoC&pg=PA663&lpg=PA663&dq=entity+framework++reset+changes&source=bl&ots=cKqjB-E9wE&sig=GGMYgVVYXbvGrsipL7TZnSYuJJI&hl=en&ei=ggvCSs2uFdT54Ab5wZmLCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=entity%20framework%20%20reset%20changes&f=false).

For the version 4, I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can dispose of the ObjectContext and make a new one. That does work.